# How to create a URI template in WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, soap

I'm new to wcf services development. I have the following problem:
I'm creating wcf-service with URI template like this:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/EmpDetails/command/?command=SaveDetails&id={id}&data{empid:{EmpID},EmpName:{EmpName},EmpAge:{EmpAge}}"
```

How can I access these values to save details?

another thing is i want this URL to be used to save details.

```
http://12.154.21.23:8888/EmpDetails/command/?command=SaveDetails&data={empid:Test,EmpName:TestName,EmpAge:26}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a class somewhere in service:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember]
    public int EmpID {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpName{get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpAge {get;set;}
}
```

Next, add this to your wcf service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/EmpDetails/command/?command=SaveDetails&id={id}&data{EmpID:{EmpID},EmpName:{EmpName},EmpAge:{EmpAge}}")]
void SaveDetails(int id, Data data);
```

and finally, add code below to class implementing wcf service interface:

```
public void SaveDetails(int id, Data data)
{
    //do smt
}
```